# Jquery to move items from one Listbox to another listbox

Tags: c#, jquery

I want to move items from one listbox to another, I have a jQuery but it is not behaving properly.
When i click left in background it causes all items to move from list2 to list1 but in front end it shows that list2 have value.
when i click submit then it causes error.
List1 is source and List2 is destination

```
$(document).ready(function () {
               $(function () {
        function moveItems(origin, dest) {
            $(origin).find(':selected').appendTo(dest);
        }

        function moveAllItems(origin, dest) {
            $(origin).children().appendTo(dest);
        }

        $('#left').on('click', function () {
            moveItems('#SelectedPanelList', '#AllPanelList');
        });

        $('#right').on('click', function () {
            moveItems('#AllPanelList', '#SelectedPanelList');
        });

        $('#leftall').on('click', function () {
            moveAllItems('#SelectedPanelList', '#AllPanelList');
        });

        $('#rightall').on('click', function () {
            moveAllItems('#AllPanelList', '#SelectedPanelList');
        });
    });
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NirtI.png)

Suppose I have 4 items in List2--a,b,c,d but only c,d are selected then in db only c,d is getting updated but i want all items which are in list2 i.e. a,b,c,d should get updated in db. Please suggest.

Htmls:
for List 1

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AllPanelList, Model.AllPanelList, new { @id = "AllPanelList", @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

For list 2

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedPanelListArray, Model.SelectedPanelList, new { @id = "SelectedPanelList", SelectListItem="true", @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [transfer items from one listbox to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576802/transfer-items-from-one-listbox-to-another)

Comment: i have four buttons, "left","right","leftall","rightall". Suppose I have 4 items in list1 and 3 items in list2, if I select an item from list2 to move it back to list1, then in front end "UI" I can see that list1 now contains 5 and list2 holds only 2 items but in view it is showing error and saying "no item in list2", when debugged I found that if I click "left" it causes all items to shift from list2 to list1.

Comment: is clone() useful for you?? you can use that for duplicating data..

Comment: It's not a duplicate question, I need help with Jquery

Comment: Sir, can you please elaborate.

Comment: @HrishikeshBagchi Please include your html in the question

Comment: watch code below, maybe useful for you

Comment: is my answer useful for you

Comment: Sir, my concern is different. I want  to move items from List1 to List2 or List2 to List1. I'm doing this using JQuery but when I click to move single item from List2 to List1, all items from List2 are getting moved into List1 and ssame is getting updated in DB., while the surprise is...In front end it is showing only one item moves from List2 to List1 but in DB level all items are now in List1.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
var $options = $("#selection > option").clone();
$('#copy').append($options);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selection">
  <option>select</option>
  <option>option1</option>
  <option>option2</option>
</select>

<select id="copy">
</select>

<button>copy</button>
```